# On the hspec argument to DensityHistogram

Tags: plotting, histograms

Below I show three *groups* of possible settings for the third (optional) argument to the `DensityHistogram` function, *hspec*.

1. `"Count"`, `"Probability"`, `"Intensity"`, `"PDF"`
2. `"CumulativeCount"`, `"CDF"`
3. `"SurvivalCount"`, `"SF"`

I have not been able to find any difference (beyond numerical error) in the results produced by different *hspec* settings from the same group.

---

Suppose that `hspec1` and `hspec2` are two different *hspec* settings *belonging to the same group* above, and let

```
dh1 = DensityHistogram[data, bspec, hspec1]
dh2 = DensityHistogram[data, bspec, hspec2]
```

My question is, briefly stated:

> For what arguments `data` and `bspec` will `dh1` and `dh2` be *different*?

---

I need to spell out what "different" means here.  Since `dh1` and `dh2` convey their information through 2-dimensional arrangements colored rectangles, I would consider them different only if the number, placement, or coloring of these rectangles differed between them.

I assume that fixing `data` and `bspec` ensures that `dh1` and `dh2` will feature the same number and placement of these rectangles.

So any difference between `dh1` and `dh2` must come from differences in the colors of corresponding rectangles.

Since the coloring of the rectangles in `dh1` and `dh2` is determined by the same color function, the previous conclusion can be rephrased as: any difference between `dh1` and `dh2` must come from differences in the arguments passed to the color function for the corresponding rectangles.

By this criterion, I have not been able to find values for `data` and `bspec` that will produce different `dh1` and `dh2` when `hspec1` and `hspec2` come from the same groups.

Actually, in some cases `dh1` and `dh2` differed due to floating-point numerical error.  This detail suggests that two *hspec* settings from the same group may lead to different execution paths, even though they produce mathematically (even if not numerically) identical results.

Below I give the details of how I arrived at the groupings above.

---

First I defined the following helper functions:

```
With[{core = ColorData["M10DefaultDensityGradient", "ColorFunction"]},
  colorFunction[z_] := (Sow[z]; core[z])
]

With[{data = BlockRandom[RandomSeed[0];
                         RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 1], {100, 2}]],
      bspec = 3},

  probe[hspec_:Automatic] := 
    Last @ Reap @
      DensityHistogram[data, bspec, hspec, ColorFunction -> colorFunction]

]
```

`colorFunction` is just a pass-through wrapper that `Sow`s its argument before passing it along to the default color function.

`probe[hspec]` just invokes

```
DensityHistogram[data, bspec, hspec, ColorFunction -> colorFunction]
```

...for fixed values of `data` and `bspec`, and then returns the arguments `Sow`ed by `colorFunction`.

Then I just evaluated

```
GroupBy[{probe[#], #} & /@
        {Automatic, "Count", "CumulativeCount", "SurvivalCount", "Probability",
         "Intensity", "PDF", "CDF", "SF", "HF", "CHF"},
        First -> Last]
```

Closer inspection of the last result's keys revealed some spurious differences resulting from using floating-point values as keys, so then I evaluated

```
GroupBy[{probe[#], #} & /@
        {Automatic, "Count", "CumulativeCount", "SurvivalCount", "Probability",
         "Intensity", "PDF", "CDF", "SF", "HF", "CHF"},
        Round[First[#], 10.^-10]& -> Last]
```

...and obtained the grouping of *hspec* settings shown at the beginning of this post.

(Incidentally, `Automatic` falls in the first group.)

Comment: The difference between "count" and "probability" should just be the values of the vertical axis -- the count being a whole number indicating how mny of each kind occur and the probability being normalized to one.

Comment: @bills: in principle, yes, but in fact there's no actual perceptible difference in the outputs generated by those two options; the density histograms look the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between "count" and "probability" is the values of the vertical axis -- the count being a whole number indicating how many of each kind occur and the probability being normalized to one. For example:

```
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 100];
{DensityHistogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", ChartLegends -> Automatic],
DensityHistogram[data, Automatic, "Count", ChartLegends -> Automatic]}
```

[image]

You can see the difference in the legend, though of course the histograms themselves look the same. You will also see the different values as popups if you pass the mouse over the data points.

Answer (score 2):

`"Count"` and `"Intensity"` will look different when the bins aren't all the same size.  Otherwise they values will be proportional and have the same colors.  The same applies to `"Probability"` and `"PDF"`:

```
data = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {500, 2}];

inequalbins = {{{-3, -3/2, -1, -1/2, 0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 
     3}}, {{-3, -3/2, -1, -1/2, 0, 1/2, 1, 3/2, 3}}};

DensityHistogram[data, inequalbins, #] & /@ {"Count", "Intensity"}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant.  I wish I could accept this one too...